# How to overlap a div above two columns in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'd like to create something like this: I'd like to have a strip of one colour (which I'll probably do with a div), which overlaps three columns:

[image]

What I would like to achieve is a layer like this, with the grey line overlapping columns 2 and 3.

```css
/* added by editor for demo purpose only */
.row > div {
  height: 80vh;
}

.row :nth-child(1) {
  background-color: red;
}

.row :nth-child(2) {
  background-color: green;
}

.row :nth-child(3) {
  background-color: blue;
}

.row :nth-child(4) {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap-4 -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!-- Body -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    1 of 3
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    2 of 3
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    3 of 3
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm not able to overlap 4 upon 2 and 3.

Comment: please put the code over here so anyone who see you question will get the proper Idea about what you want.

Comment: did you really think that this much code only you have done and you get this result please update some runnable example here so that anyone can see your example and try to solve your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go... The main trick here is `position: absolute;` which causes the gray box to be positioned above others.

```css
.col-3 {
  height: 100vh;
}

#first {
  background-color: red;
}

#second {
  background-color: green;
}

#third {
  background-color: blue;
}

#fourth {
  position: absolute;
  height: 40vh;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>

<head>

  <meta charset='UTF-8'>
  <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
  <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'>
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' integrity='sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU' crossorigin='anonymous'>
  <script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js' integrity='sha384-skAcpIdS7UcVUC05LJ9Dxay8AXcDYfBJqt1CJ85S/CFujBsIzCIv+l9liuYLaMQ/' crossorigin='anonymous'></script>

</head>

<body>

  <div class='container-fluid'>
    <div class='row d-flex align-items-center'>
      <div class='col-3' id='first'></div>
      <div class='col-3' id='second'></div>
      <div class='col-3' id='third'></div>
      <div class='col-6 offset-3' id='fourth'></div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```